# awk for loop for each line in a file

Tags: shell-script, sed, awk

I need to figure out how to get loop through a text file and for every line take the fields of name  , project #, and email, and replace them in a email template to be sent out.

So this is the text file called send.txt:

```
Project 1,Jack,Chen,06,12,test@cs.fiu.edu
Project 2,Emily,Weiss,06,12,eweiss@cs.fiu.edu
Project 3,Mary,Gonzalas,06,12,Mgonz@cs.fiu.edu
```

and this is the email template called Reminder.email:

```
Dear __FULLNAME__: 

This is a kindly reminder that our __Project__ meeting will be held on today. 

Best Regards, 
CIS5027
```

So for every line in the text file I need to replace in this email template the fields of **FULLNAME**: , and **Project** . With the corresponding values which I can do for the first line, however I cannot do it for every line.

This is my script

```
#

!/bin/sh
#Start your code from here

date= date "+%m/%d/%y"
print $date

#The following line is to scan a file called Event-member.data and return any lines with todays date and save them to a file called sendtoday.txt

grep -n $(date +"%m,%d") Event-member.data > sendtoday.txt

#The following line is to remove the first to characters of the file created above sendtoday.txt and output that to a file called send.txt.

cat sendtoday.txt | sed 's/^..//' > send.txt


#This is where im having trouble. When storing the values for the variables below of name, email, project #. The value of NR==1 thus it never goes through the rest of the lines. I've tried different solutions but none seem to work.

p=$(awk -F ',' 'NR==1{print $1}' send.txt)
n=$(awk -F ',' 'NR==1{print $2}' send.txt)
l=$(awk -F ',' 'NR==1{print $3}' send.txt)
e=$(awk -F ',' 'NR==1{print $6}' send.txt)

echo $p  $n  $l  $e

#This part is to replace the values in the email template using sed and save the modified template as sendnow.txt.  

sed -e "s/__FULLNAME__:/\ $n $l :/g;s/__Project__/\ $p /g" Reminder.email > sendnow.txt

cat sendnow.txt


#Yet to be written ... send out modified email templates.
exit 0

########
```

This is the output it produces :

```
06/12/14
Project 1 Jack Chen test@cs.fiu.edu
Dear  Jack Chen : 

This is a kindly reminder that our  Project 1  meeting will be held on today. 

Best Regards, 
CIS5027
```

As you see it did properly replace the fields but only for Jack Chen. There were 3 lines in the send.txt file so there must be 3 modified versions of the above template.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945302/assigning-awk-output-to-shell-variables this seems to solve your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no reason to use `awk` for this. You could do it directly in the shell using [`read`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read). The general format is `read foo bar` which will save the first field as `$foo` and the rest of each line as `$bar`. So, in your case, you would do something like:

```
while IFS="," read p n l foo bar e; do 
    sed -e "s/__FULLNAME__:/\ $n $l :/g;s/__Project__/\ $p /g" Reminder.email; 
done < file
```

The `IFS` is the Input Field Separator which, when set to `,` reads comma delimited fields. This lets you take each field and store it in a variable. Note that I used two extra variables `foo` and `bar`. This is because each field needs its own variable name and you have 6 fields. If you only give 4 variable names, the 4th (`$e`) will contain the fields 4 through last.

---

Now, there are various other syntax errors in your script. First of all the shebang line is wrong, you need `#! /bin/sh`, there can't be a blank line between the `#!` and the `/bin/sh`. Also, in order to assign the *output* of a command to a variable, you need to use the `` var=`command` `` or, preferably `var=$(command)` format. Otherwise, the command itself as a string and not its output is assigned to the variable. Finally, [`print`](http://www.tin.org/bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=RUN-MAILCAP) is not what you think it is. You are looking for `printf` or `echo`. So, a better way to write your script would be:

```
#!/bin/sh

date=$(date "+%m/%d/%y")
echo $date

## The following line is to scan a file called Event-member.data 
## and return any lines with todays date and save them to a file 
## called sendtoday.txt
grep -n $(date +"%m,%d") Event-member.data > sendtoday.txt

## The following line is to remove the first to characters of the file
## created above sendtoday.txt and output that to a file called
## send.txt. 
## I rewrote this to avoid the useless use of cat.
sed 's/^..//' sendtoday.txt > send.txt


## This is where you use read
while IFS="," read p n l foo bar e; do 
    sed -e "s/__FULLNAME__:/\ $n $l :/g;s/__Project__/\ $p /g" Reminder.email > sendnow.txt
    cat sendnow.txt
    ## This is where you need to add the code that sends the emails. Something
    ## like this:
    sendmail $e < sendnow.txt

done < send.txt

exit 0

########
```

Comment: This works like clockwork. Thank you so much for your help. I think this is the most concise answer. I will be seeking your help again in the future :-) .

Answer (score 4):

You  have used NR==1 condition `NR==1{print $1}`. That means it will consider the first line of `send.txt`. Use NR==2 condition to get for 2nd line and so on. OR use loop to go through all the lines like,

```
while read line
do
  p=`echo $line | awk -F '.' '{print $1}'`
  n=`echo $line | awk -F '.' '{print $2}'`
  l=`echo $line | awk -F '.' '{print $3}'`
  e=`echo $line | awk -F '.' '{print $1}'`

  sed -e "s/\__FULLNAME\__:/\ $n $l :/g;s/\__Project__/\ $p /g" Reminder.email > sendnow.txt

done<send.txt
```

Comment: This is the approach I wanted to take but couldn't get this to work out. The above IFS approach works good though. Thanks for your input. Ill try to test this again.

Answer (score 1):

maybe wrap your script in something like

```
for i in $(cat send.txt); do echo "line: $i"; done
```

?

Comment: -1. Very bad idea I'm afraid. 1) That reads the entire line (kind of, see the next point) into `$i` which does not help the OP. 2) You never want to do `for i in $(cat file)`, you should always use `while read i; do ... ; done < file` instead. With the for loop, the line will be split on whitespace so `$i` will be `Project`, then `1,Jack,Chen,06,12,test@cs.fiu.edu` for the first line. 3) This doesn't answer the question in any case since you don't address the actual issue the OP had.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat xtmp |  awk '{s++; do_aything_you_want_here }'
```

**s++ go through each line **

```
cat xtmp
111
222
333
444

cat xtmp |  awk '{s++; print($1,"QQQ") }'
111 QQQ
222 QQQ
333 QQQ
444 QQQ

cat xtmp |  awk '{s++; print($1+3,"QQQ") }'
114 QQQ
225 QQQ
336 QQQ
447 QQQ

cat xtmp |  awk '{s++; for(i=1; i<=4 ; i++) print $1 }'  # this will repeat each line 4 time

cat tmp | awk '{s++; a=a+$1; print(s" "$1" "a)}' instead of a=a+$1 you can use a+=$1
1 111 111
2 222 333
3 333 666
4 444 1110
```

Comment: How is this helpful? Answers should generally contain at least a little bit of explanatory text, especially when there's this much arcane, minimally commented code.